# Stop media player (initiated from a broadcast receiver ) from an activity android

Tags: java, android, media-player

I have an AlarmManager that notifies a broadcast receiver and the broadcast receiver plays a rigntone using the MediaPlayer class. when The alarm fires I have an activity that launches and have an OK button that should stop the media player. the question is how can I access the media player from the activity so I can stop it.

my code is as follow:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // some other code........          
        try
        {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = playAlarm(context, fileName);
            createAlarmNotificationDialog(context, mediaPlayer);
        }
        catch ( Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

private MediaPlayer playAlarm(Context context, String fileName) throws IllegalStateException, IOException
{

    File inputFile = new File("/sdcard/sampleringtone.mp3");

    //File inputFile = new File("/system/media/audio/alarms/" + fileName + ".mp3");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
    //mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
    return mediaPlayer;
}

private void createAlarmNotificationDialog(Context context, final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmNotificationActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the question is how can I access the media player from the activity so I can stop it.

You can't. You leaked it. Since you are starting an activity, anyway, have it play the ringtone.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I came up with that solution after I posted the question.

Comment: @Sam I also stick with same problem .Can you please tell me how to stop media-player in activity. Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Guys you can save mediaplayer instance in application class and access it from anywhere.
This will help you: [How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

Answer (score 2):

I am also came across with the same problem. i solved it.Create a service class and declare the media player in that class. once the alarm fires, start the service class from broadcast receiver class and stop the service from any activity. hope so it helpful.

In **broadcast receiver** class

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context,MyService.class);
            context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

from any of **activity**

```
stopService(new Intent (getApplicationContext(),MyService.class));
```